Why is my banner-Text for my three banner-Image in slider only showing on one of the banner-Image jampacked together
I am building a ecommerce project using Next.js. On creating my banner page, I implemented a react-slick slider for my images. However, I first got multiple rendering of images when I first inserted one image, but on subsequent adding of two more it now displayed the three images which is expected. The problem here is that when I tried to add banner Text to each of the images, it gave me an unexpected behavior. All the text for each banner is jampacked to only show on one of the image while on the rest of the image, nothing is showing there.
I don't know what may be responsible for this behavior as my code is not throwing any error making it difficult for me to debug.
Here is my banner component:
"use client";

import Slider from "react-slick";
import Image from "next/image";
import BannerText from "./BannerText";
import bannerone from "@/images/bannerone.jpg";
import bannertwo from "@/images/bannertwo.jpg";
import bannerthree from "@/images/bannerthree.jpg";
import { PiCaretLeftLight, PiCaretRightLight } from "react-icons/pi";

const Banner = () => {
  const NextArrow = (props: any) => {
    const { onClick } = props;
    return (
      <div
        className="p-3 bg-slate-100 hover:text-orange-600 hover:bg-white cursor-pointer duration-200  rounded-full text-2xl flex items-center justify-center z-20 absolute left-5 top-1/2"
        onClick={onClick}
      >
        <PiCaretLeftLight />
      </div>
    );
  };

  const PrevArrow = (props: any) => {
    const { onClick } = props;
    return (
      <div
        className="p-3 bg-slate-100 hover:text-orange-600 hover:bg-white cursor-pointer duration-200 rounded-full text-2xl flex items-center justify-center z-20 absolute right-5 top-1/2"
        onClick={onClick}
      >
        <PiCaretRightLight />
      </div>
    );
  };

  let settings = {
    dots: false,
    infinite: false,
    autoplay: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: true,
    nextArrow: <NextArrow />,
    prevArrow: <PrevArrow />,
  };

  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <Slider {...settings}>
        <div>
          <Image
            src={bannerone}
            alt="bannerone"
            priority={false}
            className="w-full h-full relative"
          />
          <BannerText title="Outware Picks" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Image
            src={bannertwo}
            alt="bannertwo"
            priority={false}
            className="w-full h-full relative"
          />
          <BannerText title="Seasonal Offers" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Image
            src={bannerthree}
            alt="bannerthree"
            priority={false}
            className="w-full h-full relative"
          />
          <BannerText title="Best for men" />
        </div>
      </Slider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Banner;

And my bannerText component:
import Container from "./Container";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

interface Props {
  title: string;
}

const BannerText = ({ title }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div className="hidden lg:inline-block absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full">
      <Container className="flex h-full flex-col gap-y-6 justify-center">
        <motion.h2
          initial={{ y: 30, opacity: 0 }}
          whileInView={{ y: 0, opacity: 1 }}
          transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
          className="text-7xl font-bold text-white"
        >
          {title}
        </motion.h2>
        <motion.p
          initial={{ y: 40, opacity: 0 }}
          whileInView={{ y: 0, opacity: 1 }}
          transition={{ duration: 0.6 }}
          className="text-lg text-slate-100"
        >
          Stock up on sportswear and limited edition collections on our <br />{" "}
          awesome mid-season sale.
        </motion.p>
        <motion.div
          initial={{ y: 50, opacity: 0 }}
          whileInView={{ y: 0, opacity: 1 }}
          transition={{ duration: 0.7 }}
          className="flex gap-x-4 mt-2"
        >
          <button className="py-3 px-6 rounded-full bg-slate-200 hover:bg-white duration-200 text-sm  uppercase font-semibold">
            Find out more
          </button>
          <button className="py-3 px-6 rounded-full bg-slate-200 hover:bg-white duration-200 text-sm uppercase font-semibold">
            Shop Now
          </button>
        </motion.div>
       </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BannerText;

This is the outlook of the image. the image is a slider so its only on this image all the text of the rest including itself is showing.


@Anwar Hossain, please kindly help me look in this issue sir. Thanks.

@praizjosh , kindly help me look in this problem. Thanks.

The issue here is that you are positioning BannerText as absolute without defining its reference parent. As you did here, the closest parent with a relative position is not the div representing a Slide but Slider. That's why your BannerText component doesn't slide correctly. There are several solutions, but the simplest one, in line with what you are doing, would be to set the direct parent (representing a Slide) to relative, like so:
<Slider {...settings}>
    <div className="relative">  // <-- first Slide
        <Image
        src={bannerone}
        alt="bannerone"
        priority={false}
        className="w-full h-full relative"
        />
        <BannerText title="Outware Picks" />
    </div>
    <div className="relative">  // <-- second Slide
        <Image
        src={bannertwo}
        alt="bannertwo"
        priority={false}
        className="w-full h-full relative"
        />
        <BannerText title="Seasonal Offers" />
    </div>
    <div className="relative">  // <-- third Slide
        <Image
        src={bannerthree}
        alt="bannerthree"
        priority={false}
        className="w-full h-full relative"
        />
        <BannerText title="Best for men" />
    </div>
</Slider>

